# Query for array of usernames in Parse

Tags: arrays, xcode, parse-platform

**Greetings fellow codermizters!**

Im working on this project where i try to query for users, that i have stored in an array of usernames. Is seams to work fine, but my problem is that Im ONLY retrieving user information for the LAST user in my array.

First of i have an NSMutabelArray:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *friends;
```

To get the usernames in to my array, i use the following code:

```
PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser];
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:user.username];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *senderId, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        for (PFObject *object in senderId) {

            self.friends = [object objectForKey:@"senderId"];

            NSLog(@"%@", self.friends);
```

My output log displays a nice little **array of 3 usernames**

```
2014-04-02 23:05:13.834 Ribbit[10129:a0b] Current user: Molly
2014-04-02 23:05:16.007 Ribbit[10129:a0b] Molly
2014-04-02 23:05:16.008 Ribbit[10129:a0b] Billie
2014-04-02 23:05:16.008 Ribbit[10129:a0b] Ribbit
```

And finally, to get my users, **where i only get 1**, the last user, i use this code:

```
PFQuery *download = [PFUser query];
[download whereKey:@"username" equalTo:self.friends];
[download findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *results, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {

        NSLog(@"%@", results);
```

So the last code snippet is where i run in to my problem, but don´t hesitate, Im open for an allover criticism on code as well. Does anyone know how to solve this problem? Or maybe help me understand where in my code Im doing something funky.

And I pray to the gods of objective C that this a small issue, and that what i try to do is possible, not a huge problem that i have to find a new solution for.... :)

Cheers!

I use Parse and Xcode btw...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is because you are setting up a constraint on the query in which you are comparing a property to an array. The problematic line is this one:

```
[download whereKey:@"username" equalTo:self.friends];
```

Try

```
[download whereKey:@"username" containedIn:self.friends];
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks! I have tried both equalTo: and containdIn:. EqualTo gives me user information for the last user in my array. Just changing to containdIn also only gives me the last user in my array. I also tried [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:self.friends, nil], but that gives me an "Error: bad in-value:". I think that there is something wrong with my MutabelArray. I think that i haven´t set it up in the right way. But i don´t know how to do that..

Comment: I just looked at you code again, it could be because findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock is a asynchronous job, the friends array is not being populated in time before you run the second query. Just to check if this is the case, why don't you change your first query like this: self.friends = [query findObjects]; this will block your main thread but at least you will know if thats what is causing your problem!

Comment: Thought that my NSLog(@"%@", self.friends); checks my array? Because that log contains 3 users. The fist query is in my viewWillLoad and the second is a separate UIButton, that i push after i get the NSLog from the fist query. (Im not going to run i like that in my real app, but i arranged it like that just to avoid the problem with having one Query depend in a previous Query.)

Comment: It does check it, so that means that, that is not your problem. Another solution could be to remove constraint [download whereKey:@"username" equalTo:self.friends]; then use fast enumeration in your block to check each user object against the self.friends array.